# SCNetworkReachability only works for domain names?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, connect

Given iOS's SCNetworkReachability API configured like this:

```
SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachabilityRef = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, "example.com");
SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context);
SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachabilityRef, dispatch_queue);
```

It works nice if I configure it with a domain name as in the example above. However, if I configure it with an IP address the callback is never called.

Anyone can confirm that this is the expected behavior of the SCNetworkReachability API? If so, any clues why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress instead of SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName.

Comment: What address should you use? (I think I've seen some misinformation out there.)

Comment: You can just use `struct sockaddr_in nullAddr;
    bzero(&nullAddr, sizeof(nullAddr));
    nullAddr.sin_len    = sizeof(nullAddr);
    nullAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachabilityRef
    = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL,
                                             (struct sockaddr *)&nullAddr);`

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`eppz!reachability`**](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-reachability) that works well with IP addresses, too. Simple usage like:

```
// Get status on-demand.
[EPPZReachability reachHost:@"eppz.eu"
               completition:^(EPPZReachability *reachability)
{
    if (reachability.reachable) [self postSomething];
}];
```

---

It is true. It won't work nor with `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress` (It actually works on future reachability condition changes, but the first callback never get called).

If you design needs only **on-demand reachability check**, consider using `SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags`.

A bit more at: [**Why asynchronous reachability with IP address doesn’t work?**](http://eppz.eu/blog/reachability-with-ip-address-doesnt-work/) and [**Reachability with blocks for everyday use**](http://eppz.eu/blog/reachability-with-blocks/)